# Deriving Euler's reflection formula using Hadamard's factorization formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to solve the following question:

> Show that for any s $\in \mathbb{C}: \Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s) = \frac{\pi}{sin(\pi s)}$

There are several ways to prove this where the usual approach is to use integral definition of $\Gamma$.I'm trying to solve this question using the fact that
$$\displaystyle  \Gamma(s) := e^{-\gamma s} s^{-1} \prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{s/n} (1+\frac{s}{n})^{-1}$$ where $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.using this identity then we have:
$$\displaystyle  \Gamma(s) := e^{-\gamma s} s^{-1} \prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{s/n} (1+\frac{s}{n})^{-1} \ \ \ \ \ (1)$$
$$\displaystyle  \Gamma(1-s) := e^{-\gamma (1-s)} (1-s)^{-1} \prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{(1-s)/n} (1+\frac{1-s}{n})^{-1} \ \ \ \ \ (2)$$
then multiplying $(1),(2)$ we have:
$$\displaystyle  \Gamma(s)\Gamma(1-s) := e^{-\gamma } (s(1-s))^{-1} \prod_{n=1}^\infty e^{1/n} (1+\frac{s}{n})^{-1}(1+\frac{1-s}{n})\ \ \ \ (3)$$
comparing with product form of $\frac{\pi}{sin(\pi s)}$ I tried to break to product formula in $(3)$ into two parts where one cancels out the $e^{-\gamma}$ and the other be the product form of $\frac{\pi}{sin(\pi s)}$.
But I'm stuck and I don't know how to procced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show this for real positive $s$ by the identity theorem. Using the functional equation it suffices to show: $$-s^2\cdot\Gamma(s)\Gamma(-s)=\frac{1}{\frac{\sin\pi s}{\pi s}}$$But the Hamadard product formulae on the left hand side combine to make exactly: $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(1-\frac{s^2}{n^2}\right)^{-1}$$Which equals the right hand side by the well known Weierstrass factorisation of the sine.

You can similarly use the Weierstrass product formula for the Gamma function to obtain the result. The difficulty of your approach is that the Hadamard formula makes it very non-obvious that $\Gamma(1-s)=(-s)\cdot\Gamma(-s)$.